# Reduce space between two td elemnts

Tags: css, css-position

- I have the following html code, in which I change the the position of bdg6x fields.
  **How can I reduce the gap between bdg4x and bdg0x , normally occupied by bdg6x ?**

```css
.comment {
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: -10px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class='badges'>
    <tbody>
        <tr class=info>
            <td id='bdg41'>BADGE:</td>
            <td id='bdg61' class='comment'>0002699965046</td>
            <td id='bdg01'>000026999650:</td>
            <td id='bdg21'>(n°1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class=info>
            <td id='bdg42'>BIP:</td>
            <td id='bdg62' class='comment'>0004328048703</td>
            <td id='bdg02'>000043280487:</td>
            <td id='bdg22'>(n°2)</td>        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: pos_rel]

Answer (score 3):

You must get rid of the second cell. Instead, put it inside the third one and use absolute positioning:

```css
.comment {
    position: relative;
}

.comment > span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class='badges'>
    <tbody>
        <tr class=info>
            <td id='bdg41'>BADGE:</td>
            <td id='bdg01' class='comment'><span>0002699965046</span>000026999650:</td>
            <td id='bdg21'>(n°1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class=info>
            <td id='bdg42'>BIP:</td>
            <td id='bdg02' class='comment'><span>0004328048703</span>000043280487:</td>
            <td id='bdg22'>(n°2)</td>        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td style="width:20%" id='bdg41'>BADGE:</td>
```

You can set suitable percentage for *width*. If you want, You can give min-width for *td*